# OpenCart Database and files backup from Admin area

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I have a hosted OpenCart website, installed by Host.

I want to move away from current host but he is not giving me FTP or hosting Control Panel access to download it.

I have full Admin access to OpenCart admin area and I can download DB from `Admin > Configuration > Back /Restore`

But this DB have only

```
TRUNCATE TABLE
```

and

```
INSERT INTO
```

Queries, their is no CREATE query.

Now is there any way I can run custom PHP code from OpenCart Admin area.

Or is there any way to download complete OpenCart Database (With create queries) from admin area.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can try to dump your database as can be seen here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't have direct access to DB. I have only OpenCart admin area access.

Comment: you can't backup open cart files or the data base tables from oc admin